# Как найти алгоритм для решения задачи на определение вероятности выпадения определённо суммы случайных величин?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей

С++ .Ребят подскажите как решать это,не могу найти решение\алгоритм\мат. аппарат.
В интернетах нашёл вот что.
Собственно ресурсы где я что то похожее нашёл

1. http://www.cyberforum.ru/pascal/thread1591818.html
2. https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=619
   https://acmp.ru/asp/gb.asp?id=619 (комментарии)
3. http://opennotes.ru/knowledge/vba-knowledge/algoritm-poiska-vsex-kombinacij-chisel-dayushhix-zadannuyu-summu-na-vba/
4. похожие задачи в англ учебнике в "разделе 2" http://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf
5. https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/648/504/lecture/17184?page=11&keyword_content=SMS

Сама задача:
Кубик, грани которого помечены цифрами от 1 до 6, бросают N раз. Найти вероятность того, что сумма выпавших чисел будет равна Q.
Ограничения: 1 <= N <= 500, 1 <= Q <= 3000.
Входные данные
В первой строке находятся числа N и Q через пробел.
Выходные данные

Вероятность того, что сумма выпавших чисел будет равна Q.

Примеры

Входные данные
1 1
Выходные данные
1.66666666666667E-0001
Входные данные
2 2
Выходные данные
2.77777777777778E-0002

Пробовал решить рекурсивно, но выдаёт неправильные результаты. Проверял правильность расчётов вот по этому источнику
https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=619

Моя попытка решить рекурсивно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

double funct(int n, int q) {
    if (q < n) return 0;
    if ((6 * n) < q) return 0;
    if (q == n){
        return (1.0 / pow(6.0, n));
    }
    double chance = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1;i <= 6;i++) {
        chance = funct(n - 1, q - i) / 6.0;
    }
    return chance;


};

//using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "\n 1<=N<=500; 1<=Q<=3000\n\n\n";
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout <<  std::setprecision(40)<< std::scientific << funct(a, b);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
unsigned long long m[3001][501]; // В глобальной области видимости - зануленный

unsigned long long count(int Q, int N)
{
    if (Q < N)    return 0;
    if (Q > 6*N)  return 0;
    if (N == 1)   return (Q >= 1 && Q <= 6) ? 1 : 0;
    if (Q <= 0)   return 0;
    if (N == 0)   return 0;
    if (m[Q][N] != 0) return m[Q][N];
    for(int j = 1; j <= 6; ++j)
        m[Q][N] += count(Q-j,N-1);
    return m[Q][N];
}
```

Вроде бы `unsigned long long` впритирку должно хватать...

Ну, и выводить `count(Q,N)/pow(6,N)`.

**Update**
Нет, `unsigned long long` не проходит. Надо попробовать такой вариант - с `double`. Если пройдет - ура, если не пройдет - значит, либо использовать длинную арифметику, либо искать другие пути...

```
struct { double d; bool b; } m[3001][501];

double count(int Q, int N)
{
    if (Q < N)    return 0;
    if (Q > 6*N)  return 0;
    if (N == 1)   return (Q >= 1 && Q <= 6) ? 1 : 0;
    if (Q <= 0)   return 0;
    if (N == 0)   return 0;
    if (m[Q][N].b) return m[Q][N].d;
    double r = 0;
    for(int j = 1; j <= 6; ++j)
        r += count(Q-j,N-1);
    m[Q][N].d = r;
    m[Q][N].b = true;
    return m[Q][N].d;
}

cout << count(Q,N)/pow(6,N) << endl;
```

Comment: Добрый день Harry! Решил эту задачку "сам" с помощью метода "перебора", а вот как решить её "математическим аппаратом" - не смог додуматься. Если интересно, могу приложить свой код\ссылку на гит. Как я понимаю, у вас идея похожая, что на предыдущем шаге была получения сумма минус значение текущего броска? Благодарю Вас.

Comment: Идея - рекурсивно просуммировать все возможные варианты выбрасывания на очередном этапе, но с мемоизацией - иначе рекурсия будет такой разветвленной, что время работы станет катастрофически экспоненциальным :) Сколько способов получить сумму Q с помощью N бросков? это - получить Q-1 с помощью N-1 броска + получить Q-2 с помощью N-1 броска + ... Вот и все.

Comment: Также решал задачу, только можно сразу при подсчете динамики каждый раз делить на 6(чтобы потом 6 не возводить в огромную степень).

Answer (score 1):

В вашем решении все более-менее правильно, кроме элементарной ошибки: `chance` ведь надо накапливать

```
chance += funct(n - 1, q - i) / 6.0;
```

а у вас простое присваивание поставлено.

---

Один из вариантов математики решения может быть построен так:

Если D - количество всевозможных способов разложения числа Q на сумму N натуральных слагаемых из диапазона [1, 6] (считая перестановки слагаемых разными разложениями), то величина

P = D / 6<sup>N</sup>

и даст нам требуемую вероятность.

---

Как найти величину D?

Если забыть на минутку о том, что слагаемые не должны превышать 6, то количество всевозможных разложений P(Q, N) будет равно

D<sub>0</sub> = P(Q, N) = C<sup>N-1</sup><sub>Q-1</sub> = (Q-1)! / (N-1)!(Q-N)!

Среди этих разложений будут и "неправильные" разложения, т.е. разложения с большими слагаемыми, превышающими 6. Их надо исключить из подсчета.

Если предположить, что есть как минимум одно большое слагаемое, то можно показать, что количество всевозможных разложений D<sub>1</sub> с таким слагаемым равно количеству разложений величины Q-6 на N слагаемых, умноженному на N

D<sub>1</sub> = P(Q - 6, N) * N = C<sup>N-1</sup><sub>Q-7</sub> * N = C<sup>N-1</sup><sub>Q-7</sub> * C<sup>1</sup><sub>N</sub>

Чтобы исключить из общего количества разложения с большими слагаемыми, количество D<sub>1</sub> нужно *вычесть* из количества D<sub>0</sub>.

Выполнив такое вычитание мы правильно исключили из подсчета разложения с *ровно одним* большим слагаемым. Однако мы тем самым два раза вычли количество разложений с *ровно двумя* большими слагаемыми одновременно, три раза вычли количество разложений, в которых есть *ровно три* больших слагаемых, четыре раза вычли количество разложений, в которых есть *ровно четыре* больших слагаемых, и т.д.

Это избыточное вычитание надо компенсировать.

Количество разложений с как минимум двумя большими слагаемыми равно

D<sub>2</sub> = P(Q - 12, N) * C<sup>2</sup><sub>N</sub> = C<sup>N-1</sup><sub>Q-13</sub> * C<sup>2</sup><sub>N</sub>

Это количество нужно *прибавить* обратно к величине D<sub>0</sub> - D<sub>1</sub>. Разложения с *ровно двумя* большими слагаемыми были вычтены дважды через D<sub>1</sub> и прибавлены один раз через D<sub>2</sub>. Итого: мы правильно исключили из подсчета разложения с *ровно двумя* большими слагаемыми.

Однако выполнив такое прибавление, мы три раза прибавили разложения, в которых есть *ровно три* больших слагаемых, шесть раз прибавили разложения, в которых есть *ровно четыре* больших слагаемых и т.д.

Это тоже необходимо компенсировать.

Количество разложений с как минимум тремя большими слагаемыми равно

D<sub>3</sub> = P(Q - 18, N) * C<sup>3</sup><sub>N</sub> = C<sup>N-1</sup><sub>Q-19</sub> * C<sup>3</sup><sub>N</sub>

Это количество нужно *вычесть* из величины D<sub>0</sub> - D<sub>1</sub> + D<sub>2</sub>. Разложения с *ровно тремя* большими слагаемыми были вычтены трижды через D<sub>1</sub>, прибавлены трижды через D<sub>2</sub> и снова вычтены один раз через D<sub>3</sub>. Итого: мы правильно исключили из подсчета разложения с *ровно тремя* большим слагаемым.

И так далее, и так далее, и так далее: прибавляем, вычитаем, прибавляем, вычитаем величины D<sub>i</sub>

D<sub>i</sub> = P(Q - 6*i, N) * C<sup>i</sup><sub>N</sub> = C<sup>N-1</sup><sub>Q-6*i-1</sub> * C<sup>i</sup><sub>N</sub>

Этот внешне запутанный процесс - ни что иное, как подсчет через классический [принцип включений-исключений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Наша искомая величина D будет равна

D = D<sub>0</sub> - D<sub>1</sub> + D<sub>2</sub> -
 D<sub>3</sub> + D<sub>4</sub>...

до тех пор пока мы не дойдем либо до D<sub>N</sub> (количество разложений, в которых все слагаемые большие), либо до такого D<sub>k</sub>, что Q-6*k < N

Вот и вся математика.

---

Разумеется, попытка реализации таких вычислений "в лоб" для ваших диапазонов входных значений потребует поддержки арифметики больших чисел. А для небольших значений целочисленная реализация на С или С++ может выглядеть так (даже не упрощая формулу для D<sub>i</sub>)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef unsigned long long huge_value;

huge_value C(unsigned k, unsigned n)
{
  assert(k <= n);

  if (k > n / 2)
    k = n - k;

  assert(k <= n / 2);

  huge_value num = 1, den = 1;

  for (; k > 0; --k, --n)
  {
    num *= n;
    den *= k;
  }

  assert(num % den == 0);

  return num / den;
}

huge_value pow(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
  huge_value p = 1;

  for (huge_value m = a; b > 0; b >>= 1, m *= m)
    if ((b & 1) != 0)
      p *= m;

  return p;
}

int main() 
{
  const unsigned N = 100;
  const unsigned Q = 100;

  huge_value D = 0;

  bool add = true;
  for (unsigned i = 0, q = Q + 6; i < N && q >= N + 6; ++i, add = !add)
  {
    q -= 6;
    huge_value Di = C(i, N) * C(N - 1, q - 1);
    D += add ? Di : -Di;
  }

  printf("Q = %u, N = %u: P = %lg\n", Q, N, (double) D / pow(6, N));
}
```

Хотя если вас интересует только финальная вероятность, но не точные количества разложений, то простая замена `unsigned long long` на `double` приведет к более чем удовлетворительному по точности результату.

Answer (score 0):

От "проклятия размерности" избавляет пересчёт вероятностей.
Программа на C#:

```
    public static double SumProb(int n, int q)
    {
        int m, i, j, msize = 1, size = 6 * n + 1;
        double[] prob = new double[size], pnew = new double[size];
        double vsix = 1D / 6;

        if ((q < n) || (q > 6 * n))
            return 0;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            pnew[i] = (prob[i] = 0);
        prob[0] = 1D;           // нуль кубиков - нулевая сумма
        for (m = 0; m < n; m++) // номер кубика
        {
            for (i = m; i <= 6 * m; i++)    // для каждой исходной суммы
                for (j = 1; j < 7; j++)     // и каждого исхода бросания
                    pnew[i + j] += prob[i]; // накопили вероятности новых сумм
            msize += 6;
            for(i = 0; i < msize; i++)
            {
                prob[i] = vsix * pnew[i];   // и поделили на 6
                pnew[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        return prob[q];
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Вероятности сумм при бросании нескольких кубиков" +
            "\nSumProb(1, 6) = {0}\nSumProb(1, 7) = {1} \nSumProb(4, 14) = {2}" +
            "\nSumProb(100, 100) = {3}\nSumProb(5000, 17500) = {4}", 
            SumProb(1, 6), SumProb(1, 7), SumProb(4, 14), SumProb(100, 100), SumProb(5000, 17500));
    }
```

Результаты:

```
Вероятности сумм при бросании нескольких кубиков
SumProb(1, 6) = 0,166666666666667
SumProb(1, 7) = 0
SumProb(4, 14) = 0,112654320987654
SumProb(100, 100) = 1,5306467074865E-78
SumProb(5000, 17500) = 0,00330345116336959
```

Comment: Добрый день Юрий Негометянов! Решил эту задачку "сам" с помощью метода "перебора", а вот как решить её "математическим аппаратом" - не смог додуматься. Если интересно, могу приложить свой код\ссылку на гит.Спасибо вам огромное за подробный код и результаты его запуска! Проверю чуть позже результаты исполнения вашего и своего кода! Благодарю Вас.

Comment: @Alaqota Спасибо за комплименты. Если у Вас получилось что-то своё, можете оформить это как дополнение к вопросу или как самостоятельный ответ. И если вопрос для Вас закрыт, отметьте зелёной галочкой лучший ответ, таковы правила сайта.