# Как найти вероятность того что при бросании N кубиков сумма очков будет в данном диапазоне?

Tags: python, алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

Дано число шестигранных кубиков - N. В следующем рядочке 2 числа - диапазон **(left,right)**. *Как найти вероятность того что при бросании N кубиков сумма очков будет в диапазоне (left,right)?*

*Ограничения:*

```
 N = 100
 left, right <= 600
```

*Примерчики :)*

```
 1
 1 3

 2
 11 12
```

*Ответы:*

```
 0.5

 0.083
```

*Объяснение*:
1) Возможные числа что выпадут - 1, 2, 3 , а всех (6**N = 6).

*Итог*: вероятность - 3 / (6**N = 6) = 0.5.

2) Возможные числа что выпадут - (5 + 6), (6 + 5), (6 + 6).

*Итог*: вероятность - 3 / (6**N = 36) = 3 / 36 = 0,083.

Я пытался решить задачку алгоритмически,найти все перестановки длины N в массиве (1,2,3,4,5,6), ну и тогда проверять что сумма находится в диапазоне **(left,right)**.

*Код*:

```
from itertools import product
n = int(input())
a,b = map(int,input().split())
arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
res = ["".join(i) for i in product(arr, repeat = n)]
k = 0
for i in range(0,len(res)):
    string = res[i]
    s = 0
    for j in range(0,n):
        s+=int(string[j])
    if s>=a and s<=b:
        k+=1
print(k / (6**n))
```

Comment: ну что вы написали имеет сложность что-то около `6^N` а можно за `6*N*N`. Это делается через дп. Пересчёт `F[i][k+j] = F[i-1][k] | i in [1,N] j in [1,6] k in 1..R`.

Comment: Pavel,обьясните что к чему бо не особо понимаю (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слишком длинно для комментария - пояснение толстого намёка @pavel

Создаёте таблицу `Nx6N` и заполняете её ряд за рядом.

Что в ячейке `A[K][P]`? количество вариантов набрать сумму `P` при бросании `K` кубиков.

Сумму `P` при использовании `K` кубиков можно получить при выпадении одного очка на `K`-м кубике и сумме `P-1` на `K-1` кубиках.

Эту же сумму можно получить при выпадении двух очков на `K`-м кубике и сумме `P-2` на `K-1` кубиках.

и т.д. до 6 очков.

```
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   0   0
2   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  5  4  3   2   1
```

Простая реализация на Delphi:

```
function SumProb(n, a, b: Integer): Double;
var
  Table: array of array of Int64;
  i, j, k: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Table, n + 1, 6 * n + 1);
  for i := 1 to 6 do
    Table[1, i] := 1;
  for i := 2 to n do
     for j := i to 6 * i do
       for k := Min(6, j) downto 1 do
          if j - k > 0 then
             Table[i, j] := Table[i, j] + Table[i - 1, j - k];
  Result := 0;
  for i := a to b do
    Result := Result + Table[n, i];
  for i := 1 to n do
    Result := Result / 6;
end;
```

Comment: MBo,если вам не сложно накидать какой то псевдокод,вам не сложно - а мне приятно :)

Comment: У меня ночь глубокая, уж постарайтесь разобраться на примере двух и трех кубиков

Comment: Ну окей,я то понимаю но где начальные значения брать то,ну мне не горит :)

Comment: шесть единиц для одного кубика, остальные нули.

Comment: У меня на текстувалке идёт неверный ответ,но почему я не понимаю,все зделал как вы сказали :(

Comment: Сверим `SumProb(2,11,12) 0,083333  SumProb(3,12,18) 0,375000 SumProb(5,15,25) 0,762346`

Comment: На етих тестах верно

Comment: ОК, а для больших значений у меня переполнение будет, а в питоне длинные числа встроены. А известно, для каких входных параметров неверный ответ?

Comment: Нет,к етому у меня доступа нету :(

Comment: Через переполнение может ити неверный ответ?

Comment: Да. Какой язык используется?

Comment: Вы же на Delphi писали вот и я тоже :)

Comment: Тогда будет переполнение. На Python надо переписать

Comment: Окей попробую и скажу результат)

Comment: Программа на Питоне успешно прошла,благодарю за ваш полезный ответ :)

Answer (score 3):

Вероятность попадания в диапазон равна сумме вероятностей выпадения каждого дискретного значения из диапазона.

Вероятность выпадения каждого дискретного значения суммы `S` равно отношению количества способов набрать такую сумму к количеству всевозможных исходов. Последнее равно 6<sup>N</sup>.

А количество способов набрать сумму `S` равно

Cумма для **i** от **0** до **[(S-N)/6]** слагаемых вида **(-1)<sup>i</sup> C<sup>i</sup><sub>N</sub> C<sup>N-1</sup><sub>S-6i-1</sub>**

Вычислить эту величину можно и "вручную": методом включения-исключения (как это делается я подробно расписывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779539/182825)) или через генерирующие функции. Выше приведена уже готовая формула.

Например, для задачи `2 11 12` находим количество способов выбрасывания сумм `11` и `12`, которых, по вышеприведенной формуле, `2` и `1` соответственно. Тогда вероятность равна `(1 + 2) / 36 = 0.08(3)`.